# How to build a single boost library without running out of memory on PI3

Tags: boost, build, compilation, out-of-memory, raspberry-pi3

When trying to build the boost_log library [only] for RPI3 the builder runs out of memory

I use:

```
./b2 --with-log
```

And the help text for the builder states:

```
--with-<library>        Build and install the specified <library>. If this
                          option is used, only libraries specified using this
                          option will be built.
```

after quite some time building I see:

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

Do I have any options aside from trying to cross compile on a larger system (the RPI3 has 1G RAM and a small 100M swap partition).

Answer (score 0):

You really only have two options I can think of considering your Pi's physical constraints: 1) figure out whether you could attach an external device (SSD, flash drive, etc.) and have the system swap to that, or 2) set up a cross-compilation environment on your more powerful rig.

I would personally recommend #2 as it's gonna be faster and more flexible. The internet is full of guides on how to cross-compile for Pi on multitude of hosts.